# ps2 through HDMI - no signal

Tags: technical-issues, ps2, hdmi

I'm trying to attach a ps2 to a projector through a ps2port-to-HDMI converter (like this: https://www.amazon.co.uk/EMEBAY-Converter-Adapter-Headphone-Console/dp/B079BTGWGV/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1527325174&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=ps2+hdmi+converter&psc=1)

The projector works fine when I attach my MacBook to it through HDMI but when I'm trying to attach the HDMI cable from the ps2 I get "no signal". So the projector works fine, the cable works, the ps2 works fine too (as I can hear the audio through my speakers) but something with the HDMI connection seems wrong.

Any ideas what I can do?

Comment: Does it work on any other screen? Is the projector a HDMI1.4 or HDMI 2.0 device, and what about the PS2PORT-TO-HDMI?

Comment: I don't have any other screen to test on sadly. The HDMI input on the projector is 1.4a. The PS2-HDMI adapter manual does not say what type it is.

Comment: According to the Amazon page, you should "*Set PS2 component video output to "Y Cb/Pb Cr/Br" before using the converter*". Are you sure your PS2 is set to Y Cb/Pb Cr/Br? If you don't have another screen to connect your PS2 to, you could try to find a YouTube video, with which you could attempt to set up your PS2 blind.